# How to create an redux-observable epic that waits for 2 actions before doing anything

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I would like to create an epic that listens for a explicit sequence of actions before doing work.

This epic also does not need to exist after it completes the first time.

I'm picturing something like:

```
function doTheThing(action$) {
  return action$
     // The start of the sequence
    .ofType(FIRST_ACTION)

    // Do nothing until the second action occurs
    .waitForAnotherAction(SECOND_ACTION)

    // the correct actions have been dispatched, do the thing!
    .map(() => ({ type: DO_THE_THING_ACTION }))
    .destroyEpic();
}
```

Is something like this possible with `redux-observable`?

Comment: FYI nearly all redux-observable "how do I" questions are actually just RxJS questions where the data flowing just happens to be actions, but that's not super relevant.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the reminder. Added the `rxjs` tag.

Comment: do you need access to the first action's payload? how bout the second one?

Comment: Nope, neither payload is used.

Comment: Seems like an odd pattern IMO. I would personally put that sort of state in redux itself and no need for epics to be involved

Comment: That was unsolicited advice, so feel free to ignore me if you disagree.

Comment: I agree, it is awkward. To give you more context, it's because we are trying to integrate a 3rd party analytics tool that can only be imported via script tag. We set an `onLoad` handler on the script tag that dispatches `FIRST_ACTION` and then we dispatch `SECOND_ACTION` once the user is authenticated (either via login form or cookie). Once both those actions have hit our store, we can create an instance of the 3rd party analytics tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it looks with redux observables:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/zip';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';


function doTheThing(action$) {
  return Observable
     // waits for all actions listed to complete
    .zip(action$.ofType(FIRST_ACTION).take(1), 
         action$.ofType(SECOND_ACTION).take(1),
     )

    // do the thing
    .map(() => ({ type: DO_THE_THING_ACTION }));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @jayphelps pointed out in the comments there are a couple variants depending on whether you need access to the various events and if the events must be strictly ordered. So the following should all fit:

1) Strictly ordered don't care about events:

```
action$
  .ofType(FIRST_ACTION)
  .take(1)
  .concat(action$.ofType(SECOND_ACTION).take(1))
  .mapTo({ type: DO_THE_THING_ACTION })
```

2) Strictly ordered do care about events

```
action$
  .ofType(FIRST_ACTION)
  .take(1)
  .concatMap(
    a1 => action$.ofType(SECOND_ACTION).take(1),
    (a1, a2) => ({type: DO_THE_THING_ACTION, a1, a2})
  )
```

3) Non-strictly ordered (do or don't) care about events

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  action$.ofType(FIRST_ACTION).take(1),
  action$.ofType(SECOND_ACTION).take(1),
  // Add this lambda if you *do* care
  (a1, a2) => ({type: DO_THE_THING_ACTION, a1, a2})
)
// Use mapTo if you *don't* care
.mapTo({type: DO_THE_THING_ACTION})
```

Comment: Is `forkJoin` the same as `zip` in this case? Also, how can we destroy the epic once it completes the first time?

Comment: In this case yes, Since if you use `take(1)` you are effectively completing the stream after the first event. In other contexts they wouldn't be the same because, `forkJoin` only takes the last event of each `Observable` while `zip` tries to match up each emission. The epic is destroyed implicitly in each example by virtue of the fact that it is completing.